# How to sum 2 vectors in spherical coordinate system

Tags: geometry

I have 2 vectors, and each defined by 3 coordinates: radius, azimuth and zenith
How i can sum it? Help me pls guys.
What i have done:
I found azimuth and zenith of resultant vector, by decomposition to 2 polar vectors
And it gave me 2 radiuses: radius of resultant vector for azimuth polar sum and radius of resultant vector of zenith polar sum. What can i do with them?

Comment: you want to do vector addition on spherical coordinates?

Comment: Santosh Linkha, yes you right

Answer (score 4):

Spherical coordinates are the worst thing you can use if you want to add or subtract vectors. The reason is that addition is a linear operation, while spherical coordinates are really non-linear. Already in 2D, you must invoke some trigonometrical formula to find the angle of $u+v$ when you known the vectors $u$ and $v$. In 3D the situation is even worse.

Probably, the quickest solution is to convert coordinates to usual cartesian coordinates, do the addition, and convert back to polar coordinates. See also [this discussion](http://www.reddit.com/r/math/comments/1fxoz2/adding_two_polar_vectors_together_without/).

Comment: but i hope that it's possible to take solution without cartesian, i have found 2 angles - is a 2/3 of total vector