# Sum of two vectors in spherical coordinates.

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis, spherical-coordinates

What is the sum of two vectors in spherical coordinates?

The coordinate system:

[image: coord system]

Assume we have vectors $(r_1,\theta_1,\phi_1)$ and $(r_2,\theta_2,\phi_2)$ in spherical coordinates.

I know the sum vector is not $(r_1+r_2,\theta_1+\theta_2,\phi_1+\phi_2)$ because $\hat r$, $\hat \theta$ and $\hat \phi$ are **not** fixed like Cartesian coordinates.

but I don't know what the sum vector will be then.

Also I know it is possible to convert to Cartesian and easily sum the components up and get the sum vector. but I want it in spherical system.

In the linked questions, the sum vector is not given in spherical coords. which is what I want.

Comment: lselaw of cosines, you can otherwise just use cartesian coordinates as a middle step and then angles

Comment: See these questions: [Vector sum in spherical coordinates](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17517/vector-sum-in-spherical-coordinates) and [How to sum 2 vectors in spherical coordinate system?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/790057/how-to-sum-2-vectors-in-spherical-coordinate-system)

Comment: The trouble results from the fact that you are not looking at vectors, but at the coordinates of the endpoints of a vector in a nonlinear coordinate system. You should convert back to Euclidean and calculate there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Converting them to Cartesian coordinates](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SphericalCoordinates.html) makes it easy:

$$\vec{r_1} + \vec{r_2} = \\ (r_1 \cos {\theta}_1 \sin {\phi}_1 + r_2 \cos {\theta}_2 \sin {\phi}_2) \hat{x} + \\ (r_1 \sin {\theta}_1 \sin {\phi}_1 + r_2 \sin {\theta}_2 \sin {\phi}_2) \hat{y} + \\ (r_1 \cos {\phi}_1 + r_2 \cos {\phi}_2) \hat{z} \\ =X\hat{x} + Y\hat{y} + Z\hat{z}.$$

Then you can convert back to spherical basis $(\hat{r}, \hat{\theta}, \hat{\phi})$ if you like:

$$\vec{r_1} + \vec{r_2} = \\ \sqrt{X^2 + Y^2 + Z^2}\hat{r} + \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{Y}{X}\right)\hat{\theta} + \cos^{-1}\left(\frac{Z}{\sqrt{X^2 + Y^2 + Z^2}}\right)\hat{\phi}.$$

Comment: I know that in Cartesian coordinates. I want in spherical coords. My answer to the last part ("if you like") is I like. that''s exactly what I want! :)

Comment: Added the back conversion.